# why I got : The named parameter 'shape' and 'splashColor' isn't defined On my flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget, shapes

I'm trying to add shape and splach color to my textButton But I always got :
**The named parameter 'shape'  and 'splashColor' isn't defined On my flutter application**

this is the code:

```
  home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Bluetooth"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.refresh,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: Text(
                "Refresh",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),

               
              ),
            
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              splashColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              onPressed: () async {
                // So, that when new devices are paired
                // while the app is running, user can refresh
                // the paired devices list.
                await getPairedDevices().then((_) {
                  show('Device list refreshed');
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I would be really thankful if you can help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TextButton` doesn't have those properties

Answer (score 2):

TextButton.icon doesnt have those properties. for splashcolor you can wrap your button with inkwell and give the property there and you can wrap this inkwell wth a container and in this give a decoration property with BoxDecoration and give border in here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).